# Radio wave detection timing

Tags: waves, radio

Hypothetical: I have a simple LC tuned resonant circuit, with the antenna attached to one end of a tuned parallel LC, and ground to the other, and the results amplified and passed into some kind of voltage detector/grapher. This is designed to detect the presence of a radio signal of a specific frequency (and note, it uses analog technology rather than digital).

Now imagine I send a simple radio signal on that frequency - going from off to on. I imagine this to be going from no radio signal to a consistent, full strength signal (with, I guess, the underlying radio wave consisting of a standard sine wave or similar, of consistent amplitude/strength, frequency, phase, etc.).

At what point in the wave (as it reaches the antenna) will the resonant circuit start to output a voltage? The moment the radio sine wave starts its first rise, or after a partial sine wave, or a complete one, or several?

Is there any connection between the antenna length and the time to output a voltage?

Apologies if my terminology or basic point is not clear or is wrong. My understanding of radio waves is sadly lacking.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask what the relationship between the incoming radiowave (and any other factors) and the output signal - delay, intensity, etc.

Comment: It's going to depend on the Q factor of your LC circuit. The narrower the detection band (say you want to detect 100 kHz, will you also accept 101 kHz, or 100.1 kHz, or 100.01 kHz?) the longer it will take the circuit to respond.

Comment: Is there a formula or relationship that would tell me about that? Will the response always be consistent, and if so, how consistent (ie will it always trigger on the same part of a radio wave, or after a certain number of cycles, or what?)?

Comment: If  you denote the *effective*, say 3dB, bandwidth of the circuit by $B$ (effective, ie., including both source and load impedances) then its *effective* response time is approximately $\tau_e=m/B$. Here $m$ is a number between 0.5 and 2. During its transient the number of RF cycles involved are then roughly $f\tau_e$.

Comment: @hyportnex, thanks - do you have a name, link or source for that formula so I can read up on it a bit more?